# Filling PMP Application as Consultant - Project Role and Organization Details

Tags: pmp

As a person who is currently working as Consultant at an IT Consulting Firm which roles have ranged from Project Manager, Project Coordinator, Project Expeditor and Project Contributor, how should I fill out the application for the PMP certification?

1. **What should I put down as my project role?**

   - Should it be "Consultant" for all client projects?
   - Should I put down "Other" and then say "Consultant - Project Coordinator"?
   - Does anyone know the exact definitions of the roles listed in the PMP application form? They do not match the roles defined in PMP terms
2. For organization details, **should I put the information of the consulting company I work for or should I put the information of the client organization** for whom the project was being conducted?

All constructive feedback is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

What should I put down as my project role?

*It should be our current Role. Your roles will be different for different projects,  sometime Project Lead/TL, consultant, Developer, Analyst, Module Lead etc*

For organization details

*Your payroll company and the institution which got the contact hours.*

Answer (score 0):

Rather than just put Consultant, you should put down the actual role you were fulfilling on each particular project (PM, Project Coordinator, etc).  For the organization, put down your consulting agency since you were directly employed by them.

Comment: This can be impossible if you do short contracts (like I do). Trying to list all of your 2-4 week engagements over the last 3-4 years is bloody impossible.

Comment: In that case you have to use common sense.  Try grouping "like" roles and then list the various clients for whom you were fulfilling those roles.